# How can set header Request in angular for redirection URL

Tags: angular

When we click the link then redirect to other domain. how can possible set the request header in other domain from angular. We have don't using HttpClientModule and Interceptor in our code. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to a domain that opens by the browser, you're not supposed to have any headers with it.
Browsers don't support it ( in order to keep it simple and allow users to only click a simple link and get to the address they want.)

Comment: My link open in a same tab but not added header. we are using below piece of code.                                                            xhr.open('method', "post");
xhr.open('action', actionUrl);
xhr.setRequestHeader('iv-user', party_id);
xhr.send();

Comment: Please help how can set header Request for different domain. we are using below and facing cors policy issue.   `"post"); xhr.open('action', actionUrl); xhr.setRequestHeader('iv-user', party_id); xhr.send();`

Comment: Please share your code of the HTTP request and all the relevant code

Comment: When we set the request header on other domain then getting cors policy issue.
Please help me.

`component.html
 <a (click)="managePolicy(policy)">Authorization pending</a>

component.ts
managePolicy(policyData){
    let party_id = sessionStorage.getItem('party_id') ? sessionStorage.getItem('party_id') : null;
    let actionUrl = 'https://otherDomain.com';   
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('action', actionUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('iv-user', party_id);
    xhr.send();
}`

Comment: if you getting CORS that's means this `https://otherDomain.com` server not let you access from your domain . that's something you need to solve on server side

Comment: Is the code I sent you? Is that the right way to set request header from angular side. We are not using httpHeaders or Interceptor.

Comment: but if you want to send a simple request, why not use the HTTPClient service?

Comment: We are redirecting to that URL only with  as a name of 'iv-user' request header.